# Terminology: does this situation correspond to an anisotropic but linear dielectric?

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics, terminology, material-science, dielectric

Let us assume that for a dielectric the relation $${\vec D}=\epsilon\vec E$$ holds where $\epsilon$ is independent of $\vec E$. However, let $\epsilon$ is not a scalar number but a tensor (or a $3\times 3$ off-diagonal matrix). I am sure that this represents an anisotropic dielectric. But I am not sure whether it will be called a linear dielectric or not.

My guess is that unless $\epsilon$ is a function of $\vec E$, whether or not $\epsilon$ is a scalar number, the dielectric is called linear. Textbooks are not clear on this matter. I feel isotropic and linear are two mutually independent concepts: a dielectric can be linear without being isotropic and vice versa. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 percent correct. A material is linear when the material law is what a mathematician will call a linear mapping, i.e.
$$
\vec{D}\left(\vec{E}+\lambda \vec{E}'\right) = \vec{D}\left(\vec{E}\right)+\lambda\vec{D}\left(\vec{E}'\right)
$$
for all... Nothing about direction in this statement.

And the material is isotropic when the material law is an isotropic tensor function, i.e. for all orthogonal mappings $A \in O_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ (usually $n=3$) we have
$$
A\vec{D}\left(\vec{E}\right) = \vec{D}\left(A\vec{E}\right)\,.
$$
Nothing about linearity in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would call this situation a linear dielectric:

From [Electrostatic Fields in Matter](http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY217/LectureNotes/Chapter4/LectureNotesChapter4.html#Heading318):

> Materials in which the induced polarization is proportional to the
> electric field are called linear dielectrics.

This is definitely the case here even though the induced polarization is not necessarily in the same direction as the incident electric field.

Answer (score 0):

Isotropy means that the relation between $\vec D$ and $\vec E$ is independent of the direction of $\vec E$. This also implies that $\vec D$ is parallel to $\vec E$:
$$\vec D = \vec D (E) \hat E.$$
This is for non-dispersive media, i.e. the value of $\vec D$ at any given time depends only on $\vec E$ at that time. For dispersive media, $\vec D$ can be related to $\vec E$ in a more complex, non-linear way, depending on the history of $\vec E$ as well.

For a general, dispersive linear material,
$$\vec D(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^tdt'\boldsymbol{\epsilon}(t-t')\vec E(t')$$
where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}(t)$ represents the impulse response of a linear system with $\vec E(t)$ as input and $\vec D(t)$ as output. This is equivalent to a frequency-dependent permittivity:
$$\vec D(\omega) = \boldsymbol{\epsilon}(\omega)\vec E(\omega).$$
For a non-dispersive linear medium, these reduce to
$$\vec D = \boldsymbol{\epsilon}\vec E.$$
Note that isotropy has not been invoked in these equations. So isotropy and linearity can be regarded as independent properties of the medium: one doesn't require or imply the other.

Comment: The question was about nonlinearity and isotropy, not on dispersion - where in the general case you should include spatial dispersion as well (wave-vector dependence of the FT).